# Dynamic proxy combined with IronPython

Tags: ironpython, postsharp

I'm looking for a tool that would allow me to log method parameters ( basically something like PostSharp ) and return values at runtime. The tricky part is that I would like to do this for a Ironpython exposed C# class. I tried using

[KingAOP](https://github.com/AntyaDev/KingAOP%20KingAOP)

and

[Afterthought](https://github.com/vc3/Afterthought)

Both without success.

I also used [PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/) and it works with it. But I'd rather use an open source library. I assume I can't get KingAOP working for this because it is dynamic based and iron python does some magic that overrides the default dynamic object behavior.

So has anyone done any parameter/return value logging using a AOP wrapper with IronPython